# How to create Lightroom's texture tool in other software?

Tags: lightroom, texture

I am new to "advanced" photo editing and I figured Lightroom's Texture tool is amazing at smoothening skin without losing the detail in "detail-rich" areas like eyes, clothes, etc. However, Lightroom is extremely expensive for me and I am planning to buy a software with perpetual license (Like ON1 Photo RAW or CaptureOne); I want to check if it's possible to achieve this in some other software? I figured the skin smoothening filter in ON1 does not work very well for this.

Upon checking the internals of the Texture (+Clarity & Dehaze) tool, I figured it works by reducing contrast and keeping the same saturation in mid-detail areas (Areas with not many sharp edges, and not completely flat as well) - Please correct me if I am wrong. I tried mocking it in ON1 Photo RAW by creating a mask over the skin to smooth and reduce contrast, but could not get it working exactly.

Any recommendation?

Comment: I have my doubts you can find such tool in other software. Such tools (and algorithms) are usually subject of company secrets and other companies can mostly emulate the work of "texture" tool (based on the experimental data).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I totally agree. I did figure out that ON1 Photo RAW has a Portrait AI filter that let's the user change skin based off of frequency separation - same principal as Lightroom. It's extremely close to the Texture tool in Lr. Luminar Neo has a similar tool too, but ON1's Portrait AI with skin smoothening using Frequency Separation is the closest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no substitute to Lr's Texture tool as of now, however there are other tools that come close.

- ON1 Photo RAW's Portrait AI with skin editing and frequency separation will largely do the trick on human subjects.
- Luminar Neo's Skin AI can be used to get very similar result as Lr's Texture tool on human subjects.